# window onunload/onbeforeunload events don't work?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've used the event in other projects/games but it doesn't seem to be working on this one. onload event is working fine tho.

Script is linked on the bottom of the html before the < /body > tag

the code in client.js

```
(() => {
    // Player Closes window
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        sock.emit('player-leave', player);
        alert('window.addEventListener');
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        sock.emit('player-leave', player);
        alert('window.onbeforeunload');
    };
    window.onunload = function(event) {
        sock.emit('player-leave', player);
        alert('window.onunload');
    };
})();
```

Event doesn't pass throu and no alert is shown.

Link to git repository for full code: https://github.com/Tw1ster95/drawitgame

EDIT: I guess i found a way to use the socket id for the disconnect of player but i'm still wondering why doesn't it emit on beforeunload.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem of `onbeforeonload`. The reasons why `alert` doesn't work is because modern browser will ignore the `alert()` when doing `beforeunload`.

> The HTML specification states that calls to window.alert(),
> window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during
> beforeunload event. See the HTML specification for more details.

Check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

If you run your webpage and keep pressing a reloading key, you may able to see the error message `Blocked alert() when beforeunload` in the console.

Comment: I actualy saw that earlier but it doesn't explain why the sock.io event isn't emiting. When i console.log the player on the other end it doesn't work. i actualy have the full code on github i'll edit my question with the link.